# what is this pink flower?

Tags: identification

[image: pink flowers]

I got these flowers from a Home Depot in Pennsylvania. The tag does not mention the name. Can anyone help me identify what kind of flowers these are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's either a Dipladenia or a Mandevilla - they are very similar and each may be named incorrectly at the point of sale.  Until they start producing growth, it's quite hard to tell them apart, though because of the flower colour and the neatness of the leaves in your image, my money's on yours being Dipladenia. Care for both is similar anyway; both need warm temperatures (nothing below 65/70 deg F at night), with bright daylight, but not so much direct sun - Mandevilla, though, will climb quite rapidly and will need more support than Dipladenia. More info here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/vines/mandevilla/growing-a-dipladenia.htm